# How to change nodejs schema according to my requirement

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have following data I want put data like below but my schema does not allow me what I do, to send data like below please check. when I put only single {} body it's working fine but I want more then one bodies

```
    //Request body
            {
            "title" : "test10",
            "sch_start": "2017-04-3",
            "sch_end":"2017-04-3"
        },
        {
        "title" : "test11",
        "sch_start": "2017-04-4",
        "sch_end":"2017-04-4"

        }
```

---

```
       import mongoose, {Schema} from 'mongoose';

    /**
     * Model to store Calendar entries of Engineer
     */
    var EngineerScheduleSchema = new Schema({
      title: { type: String, default: ''},                             
      available: { type: Boolean, default: false },
      sch_start: { type:Date, default: Date.now },
      sch_end: { type:Date, default: Date.now }
    });

    export default mongoose.model('engineer_schedule', EngineerScheduleSchema);
```

---

```
  //  Main Model Mongoose Schema
     schedule: [EngineerSchedule.schema]
```

---

```
//API Method 
export function updateSchedulecalendar(req, res) {  
  var responseSchedule;

  //Insert

    return Engineer.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, { $addToSet: { schedule: req.body } }, { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true, runValidators: true }).exec()
      .then((entity) => {
        if (entity) {
          responseSchedule = entity.schedule;
          return EngineerEvents.emit(engineerEvents.updatedSchedule, req.user, entity);
        }
        else {
          return res.status(404).end();
        }
      })
      .then(()=> { return res.status(200).json(responseSchedule); })
      .catch(handleError(res));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Since you are trying to send many schedules, your request body should look like:

```
    [{
            "title" : "test10",
            "sch_start": "2017-04-3",
            "sch_end":"2017-04-3"
        },
        {
        "title" : "test11",
        "sch_start": "2017-04-4",
        "sch_end":"2017-04-4"
     }]
```

Second, you should take a look at *findOneAndUpdate* documentation, cause it seems to me that you are sending two schedule objects (*test10* and *test11* ) to be updated on a single schedule specified by *req.params.id*. It does not make much sense.

If you are looking to update multiple schedules in a single request, maybe you should implement a bulk update. Take a look at [bulk functionality](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/), I would implement something like this:

```
export function updateSchedulecalendar(req, res) {  
  var responseSchedule;

  var bulk = db.items.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
  // Iterate over every schedule sent by client
  for(schedule in req.body) {
    // Generate a new update statement for that specific document
    bulk.find( { title: schedule.title } ).update( { $set: { sch_start: schedule.sch_start, ... } } );
  }
  // Execute all updates
  bulk.execute().then(function() {
    // Validation
  });
}
```